# popover javascript in foreach php

Tags: php, javascript, foreach

Hello i want to do something like this but i repeat my script in the foreach anyone can help me for not repeat the script javascript.

```
foreach($items as $i){
    <script>
        $(function(){
        $('#pop<?php echo $i->ID; ?>').popover({
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'bottom',
          html : true,
          content: function() {
            return $('#pop-content<?php echo $i->ID; ?>').html();
        }});
      });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Java `!=` JavaScript...

Comment: Why use a `foreach` loop in PHP to bind popovers when you could (and should) be using a class for that? Just add `.popover` to the elements, and then use `$('.popover').popover()`?

Comment: What are you trying do?

Comment: for each id generate a content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using PHP:

```
<?php
  echo '
    <script>
    var initPopup = function(id) {
      $("#pop" + id).popover({
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: "bottom",
        html : true,
        content: function() {
          return $("#pop-content" + id).html();
      }});
    }
  ';
  echo '$(function(){';
  foreach($items as $i){
    echo 'initPopup("<?php echo $i->ID; ?>");';
  }
  echo '});';
  echo '</script>'
?>
```

Comment: Thx Krasimir for your help !